# Inventory items by lastmodified date in netsuite using query

Tags: api, postman, netsuite

I want to get the list of inventoryItems in netsuite by its lastModified date.This is what I have tried: *{{REST_SERVICES}}/query/v1/suiteql*

```
Body : 

{
    "q": "SELECT * FROM inventoryItems dateModified >= '08/17/2020'"
}

but it says error:

Invalid search query Search error occurred: Failed to parse SQL [SELECT * FROM inventoryItems dateModified >= '08/17/2020']: syntax error, state:961(10102) near: >=(1,43)\nno_root_node(-1000) near: no root node(0,0).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use SuiteQL, you can use `Record Collection filtering`

```
GET /record/v1/inventoryitem/?q=lastModifiedDate AFTER "8/17/2020"
```

https://[account].app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_1545222128.html

Comment: Can we use it with time stamp?

Comment: Why can't I get all fields of the items in the api call instead of links?Is there anyway to do it?I have been searching to do that for a while...but while calling a collection api the only query parameters that I am allowed to use is q,limit & offset..I want to get all fields of inventory items as a collection

Answer (score 2):

The record and field names are in the Analytics Browser: https://[account].app.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2020_1/analytics/record/item.html

```
{
    "q": "SELECT id, itemid FROM item WHERE itemtype = 'InvtPart' AND lastmodifieddate >= '08/17/2020'"
}
```

SELECT * throws UNEXPECTED_ERROR. You will have to list down the fields you need.

Comment: But do u know how to get the data without using suiteql? My manager does not want me to use suiteql..I want to get inventory items using lastmodified date without using suiteql

Answer (score 1):

The error is straightforward, your SQL query is invalid. It's missing a WHERE clause.

Try changing

```
SELECT * FROM inventoryItems dateModified >= '08/17/2020'
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM inventoryItems WHERE dateModified >= '08/17/2020'
```

Comment: Invalid search query Invalid search type: inventoryItems

Comment: I don't think I can get the result via suiteQL. Does anyone know how to get inventoryItems by lastModifiedDate field using Rest APIS of netsuite?